# What is the proper name for embedding powershell in text files within <% %> tags

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that I know gets transformed using powershell variables and commands on octopus, but I can't remember what this substitution mechanism is called.

example of the syntax:

```
the feature is: <% if ($Feature -eq 1) { %>on<% } else { %>off<% } %>
```

When this file is processed the result would be:

> the feature is: on

or

> the feature is: off

depending on the value of `$Feature`

Please help. My brain is on fire.

Comment: the `<# #>` structure is for multiline comments ... IF the last one is at the beginning of a line. i am shocked that it works the way your code works. [*grin*]

Comment: I personally have never seen or use Octopus, but Is this not defined in the Octopus product/admin guides? I've never seen PS code written this way as those chars '<%%>' would just cause errors and failures. What you are showing is just a substitution or switch. yet, doing what you have would be akin to a script block, but that use braces (curly braces) and not <%%>. If this was <##>, then that is a comment block. I live by a philosophy of ABL (always be learning), so, time to look up what you show here. Yet, inserting stuff is often called embedding. That <%%>, is not a thing neither is %><%.

Answer (score 0):

After looking all over the place and asking some internal people that I hadn't thought to ask I found that this syntax is used by a powershell module called [EPS (Embeded PowerShell)](https://github.com/straightdave/eps).

This module can be used to process text files as templates for variable substitution. The relation to Octopus was completely incidental.